# Asking for plus.login and userinfo.profile scope permissions at the same time in Google+ API

Tags: android, ios, oauth, google-plus

I'm a little confused. Using Google+ Android SDK to log in a user to my app and get his profile details. The manual at https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth clearly says

> You should **not** request `userinfo.profile` or `plus.me` in combination with `plus.login` scope as they are implicitly included and would create a confusing permissions dialog for your user.

So I asked only for `plus.login` scope (and `userinfo.email` scope, but that is not related). Tried debugging the token by calling

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Here's what I get back :

```
{
    "issued_to": "534771845378-3668o318pburvuhrukgj7pao3ir****.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "audience": "534771845378-3668o318pburvuhrukgj7pao****.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "user_id": "106027222137637*****",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "expires_in": 2279,
    "email": "****@****.com",
    "verified_email": true,
    "access_type": "online"
}
```

And here is the response I got trying to get the user profile by calling

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

```
{
    "id": "10602722213763777****",
    "email": "****@****.com",
    "verified_email": true,
    "hd": "****.com"
}
```

Clearly you can see that there aren't any user profile details in this response.

When I add the `userinfo.profile` scope, like google says you **shouldn't**, I get a good response with the user's profile details.

What is going on Google ?

Comment: this is realted to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066222/google-api-doesnt-return-profile-name-with-login-request?rq=1

Comment: and also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124134/how-to-get-the-email-from-https-www-googleapis-com-plus-v1-people-me-call-usin

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky, use following scope

```
scope = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+profile
```

If this is required don't forget to upvote.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, really appreciate your post!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but apparently you can't get email and user's profile in the same api call.

When asking for `plus.login` and `userinfo.email` scope, you should first use the access token to call `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo` endpoint and get the email address.
Then, if you want the user's profile details, you need to call `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` endpoint (with the access token of course).

This makes it unnecessarily complicated, Google ?

Answer (score 0):

I found I got the e-mail and profile using the following scopes:

'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 'email', 'profile'